# How to disable row-clicked events for an entire column in b-table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Working with the bootstrap-vue component b-table I am using the @row-clicked event to link to another page. The issue occurs in the row where i added checkboxes. I am able to disable the row-clicked event for the checkbox but the rest of the column still links to the other page. So if a user miss-clicks by a smidgen while selecting rows with the checkboxes they are brought to another page. The b-table is part of a vue-component.

So my question is how do i disable the @row-click event for an entire column of b-table instead of just for the checkbox in the column?

Here is my table. I have been throwing @click.native.stop everywhere trying to solve this. the template slot=" " is the column with the checkboxes. I attempted to disable a span of text and the text itself was clickable without triggering the row event but empty space in the box did trigger the row-clicked event.

```html
<b-table ref="table" striped hover responsive foot-clone
      :items="values"
      :fields="fields"
      :filter="filter"
      :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
      :set-desc.sync="sortDesc"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      @row-clicked="onRowClick"
      @filtered="onFiltered">
          <template slot=" "  v-on:click.stop="" @click.native.stop slot-scope="row">
              <b-form-checkbox @click.native.stop :value="row" block name="checkbox" size="lg"  @change="boxChecked(row)"></b-form-checkbox>
          </template>
          <span slot="url" slot-scope="data" v-html="data.value"> </span>
          <span slot="connected"  @click.native.stop v-on:click.stop="" style="height:100%; width:100%"slot-scope="data" v-html="data.value"></span>
          <span slot="enabled" slot-scope="data" v-html="data.value"></span>
          <span slot="powered" slot-scope="data" v-html="data.value"></span>
          <template slot="vlans.tagged" slot-scope="data">
                  <div v-for="tagged in data.item['vlans.tagged']">
                      {{tagged}}
                  </div>
          </template>
          <template slot="table-caption"> Total count {{totalRows}} </template>
  </b-table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, Bootstrap Vue does not seem to directly give you the column you clicked on. You are able to retrieve it from the actual MouseEvent though using `srcElement` on the Event <sup>[(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement)</sup> and `Node.previousSibling` <sup>[(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling)</sup>.

```
onRowClicked(item, index, event) {
  const element = event.srcElement;
  const isFirstElement = !element.previousSibling;
  if (!isFirstElement) {
    this.$router.push('/mythingy');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using event.srcElement.cellIndex gives the column number of the table that the mouse clicked on. So with that I can make any row not trigger loading the new page.

Comment: Using srcElement causes errors in firefox so i used event.target.cellIndex instead to get the column number for filtering the on.row.click event